# Why doesn't Copy or \copy work for me in Pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, plpgsql, psql

I am trying to import data from a csv into postgres. I have tried the following and got the following errors:

```
Copy TA_Files 
FROM 'C:\Users\ABla47\Documents\TA 11.19.21.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

> ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\ABla47\Documents\TA
> 11.19.21.csv" for reading: Permission denied
>
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a
> file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
>
> SQL state: 42501

Then I tried:

```
\Copy TA_Files 
FROM '\Documents\TA 11.19.21.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""
>
> LINE 1: \Copy TA_Files

Can someone help me know what format I need to use to get the data from the csv into the table?

Thanks

Comment: `\copy` command has to be a single line e.g. `\Copy TA_Files  FROM  ...`

Comment: Like this? \Copy TA_Files FROM '\Documents\TA 11.19.21.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
I'm still getting a syntax error...

Comment: Add the command to your question along with the syntax error. Though I notice there are no commas between options.

Comment: Forgot the part about the commas, I realized that is the older syntax which is still allowed. If I remember correctly you need to do `'/Documents/TA 11.19.21.csv'` even though you are on Windows. I don't have a Windows install to test on.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. I think I have the syntax wrong for \copy. It doesn't get past the "\" because it thinks its a syntax error.

Comment: `\copy` only works directly in `psql` you can't use it inside PL/pgSQL or a different SQL client

Comment: Under windows postgresql runs with the NETWORK_SERVICE system account. This account has no read rights to your home directory `C:\Users\ABla47`.

Comment: What user interface are you using?  "psql"? "PG-Admin"? "Access?"

Comment: I'm using Pgadmin 4

Comment: Any work around for this? I found there to be a manual import, but it would be nice if I had a code to do it...

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me: 
I placed the files in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4` directory and copied it from there.

```sql
COPY superstore_people(person, region)
FROM 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\superstore_people.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but just had this problem and hadn't seen this solution on stackoverflow yet. This was the simplest solution for me.

https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-fix-permission-denied-error-while-importing-a-csv-file-in-postgresql/

just go to file properties -> security -> edit -> then in 'object names' type 'Everyone'. ->apply changes

Answer (score -2):

The file which I copied to the Postgres folder, worked for importing a `CSV` file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!